# Correctly Interpreting Regression Coefficients For Financial Returns Data

Tags: regression, finance

I'm running some regressions on daily return data, and I want to make sure I'm interpreting the coefficients correctly.

Right now `X` is a single column of values that represent the daily returns for the S&P 500.  `y` are the daily returns for a stock.

I'm not doing standardizing or log transformations right now.

If the coefficient for `X` is 0.9, can I interpret that as meaning if the S&P 500 were to go up by 1%, the price of the stock would go up by 0.9%?

I understand there are possible issues with how I'm handling the data, I just want to make sure I'm understanding the model output correctly.

If you would like, here is some reproducible code in python if you have the `yfinance` module installed on your computer.

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

google = yf.Ticker('GOOGL')
g      = google.history(period='max')
sp     = yf.Ticker('SPY')
s      = sp.history(period='max')
s['X'] = (s['Close'] / s['Close'].shift()) - 1
g['y'] = (g['Close'] / g['Close'].shift()) - 1
data = s.merge(g, left_index = True, right_index = True)
data.dropna(inplace = True)
X = data[['X']]
y = data['y']
mod = LinearRegression()
mod.fit(X, y)
```

In this case `mod.coef_` returns a value of 0.97.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you obtain the estimate of "0.97%"?

Comment: @whuber Should have been 0.9.  Fixed the typo.

Comment: OK.  Of greater import is how you intend your interpretation to be understood.  Do you really want your listeners to believe that this stock is driving the S&P 500 in such a strong, determined way?  For more about this, search our site for posts that discuss the terms "regression," "correlation," and "causality."

Comment: @whuber I definitely would not do that and have no intention on making those statements.  I really just wanted to double check that I was thinking about the particular detail in this question correctly.  I understand there's a lot more to it than what I mentioned.